# What are the lighter areas in this cube

Tags: faces

I'm completely new to Blender. I've taken a cube someone else modeled and trying to create Ambient Occlusion for it. I've noticed that in edit mode, some of the faces are lighter than others. What does it mean and if it requires fixing, how? File is [image]

[image]

Comment: At first glance I would say, they haven't got the orange tinted overlay that indicates selection. So they are simply unselected. The circle ones have selected edges to the center, but when you're in _Edge Select_ mode instead of _Face Select_, then the faces won't be shown as selected when one or more border edges are unselected. The only thing I can't tell from the screenshot is why the faces adjacent to unselected ones seem to be selected (because they share unselected edges) and in my Blender unselected edges are black, not white - but this might be a customized color setting of you.

Comment: maybe you should upload your blend file so we don't have to guess what happened....

Comment: @Chris, I thought it'll be a trivial answer. But where do you recommend I upload to?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I selected with 'a' in face select mode. I just tried it with edge select mode and the areas went away. Still not following why this faces are not selected in face mode...

Comment: just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: @Chris done....

Comment: Those faces are selected. Also, some of them are overlapped. I suggest learning a little bit more about Blender basics before diving into the more complicated stuff, you'll save yourself from some headaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you have several objects (each cube is an object in your case).

In "Edit mode" (you can toggle between Edit mode and Object mode with <kbd>TAB</kbd>) you can select vertices, edges and faces.

[image]

In your case the face selection is active.

Blender differentiates between 3 states:

unselected (gray in your case), active (can only be one single face per object - white), and selected (can be multiple faces - orange).

[image]

if you press <kbd>A</kbd> in object mode, all objects will be selected.

This looks like this:

[image]

Same rule here: only one object can be active (orange), but many can be selected (red/darker orange).

If you then go in edit mode, you see this:

[image]

and because every cube is an object, each of these objects/cubes have one active face, which is white. And all other faces are selected, thats why they are orange.